# Using or partially re-using an Angular service inside a React micro-frontend

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, reusability, micro-frontend

I'm working on an application that uses single-spa to integrate both Angular and React Micro-frontends onto an Angular host page.

React micro frontends have recently been introduced into the app where as before it was only an Angular host page with various Angular micro frontends.

I have some angular services in a separate library that need to be used in the react micro frontends but I definitely want to re-use as much code as possible or if possible straight up use the angular services inside the react micro frontend without much change to the original code.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AngularService {
 ...
}
```

Some initial ideas that I had was to have a typescript "service" serve as the base and use that within the angular service.

```
export class BaseService {
 ...
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AngularService {
 ...
 constructor() {
   this.baseService = new BaseService();
 }
 ...
}
```

Another idea was to have three libraries in total, a common library and then an angular and react specific library which depend on the common library.

In addition, what is the equivalent of an Angular service in react? React Hooks?

I'm guessing I can also just not use services, and just create a typescript module that exports single functions?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Let me ask you this: do you think your application is going to be easier or harder to build on and maintain if it's using both Angular and React?

To my mind, it is almost certainly going to be way more complicated. It sounds like you're an Angular dev and now have to learn React, is that a good use of your time? These are somewhat similar tools for building a UI, do you absolutely have to use both in the same application or would sticking with Angular work fine?

Comment: I'm actually a React developer, I learned Angular this past year and would say I'm pretty advanced at Angular already. Was tasked with creating a generator to build react micro frontends and expanding our app to support react. Other teams that strictly use react will integrate their apps as micro frontends onto our angular host app, so to answer the question, yes using both angular and react are a requirement.